# Problem while trying to create react app using npx

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create react app using ngx but it is not creating the app, it is just installing node modules and package json file.

below is the where it is stopping.
[image]

[[image: updated error][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBmtQ.png)

I have node version 8.9.2
npm version 5.5.1
nvm version 1.1.5

C:\Windows\System32>create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in C:\Windows\System32\my-app.

┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                  npm update check failed                  │
│            Try running with sudo or get access            │
│           to the local update config store via            │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) C:\Users\acer.config │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Windows\System32\my-app\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
>   node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
>
> core-js@3.6.4 postinstall C:\Windows\System32\my-app\node_modules\core-js
>   node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
>
> core-js-pure@3.6.4 postinstall C:\Windows\System32\my-app\node_modules\core-js-pure
>   node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

- cra-template@1.0.3
- react@16.13.1
- react-scripts@3.4.1
- react-dom@16.13.1
  added 1604 packages from 750 contributors and audited 931146 packages in 240.793s

58 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: Please copy and paste from npm rather than embedding images of the console.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might need Node to be at least 8.10: https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app

> You’ll need to have Node >= 8.10 and npm >= 5.6 on your machine.

I would try upgrading Node and reinstalling create-react-app to see if that helps!

Comment: I have updated to all latest versions but still it is not creating the app

Answer (score 0):

Try installing create-react-app globally by :

```
npm i -g create-react-app
```

Then :

```
create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: Hi I tried but it is of no use , Updated my question with recent error

Comment: It is not working in admin mode also , please look the issue i have updated now